# Probability of predicting the lottery

Tags: probability

Are the odds of predicting that someone would win the lottery the same as just some random person winning the lottery, or are they different probabilities? Because to me, if I read that someone had won the lottery, I wouldn't be that amazed, but if someone predicted that a particular person would win and that prediction came true, I'd think that's far more far-fetch.

Comment: Sure. The probability that a **specific** person wins in a lottery is much smaller than the probability that an **arbitrary** person of a population wins in a lottery. In the first case there are much more persons who have the chance of winning. Sounds it logic to you ?

Comment: You do not know how many tickets the person bought.  If someone buys one of every combination, then they will "win" the lottery.  This then is not a surprise.

Comment: Would anyone know how to calculate the probability of a specific person winning the lottery then?